# Get Sharepoint List Items - Sharepoint Threshold Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, csom

When i try to get the sharepoint list items using CSOM C# it gives a threshold error as it contains more than 5k items. Also i cannot make any changes to the threshold value nor add indexing due to limited permission. Please suggest a way around to get the items using csom c#.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this link : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171373/sharepoint-2013-list-threshold-limit

Comment: This is one of the best articles you can read on
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C